# Tailing log is slow

Tags: python, logging, pythonanywhere

Hosted on pythonAnywhere, working inside a jupyter notebook,  I create a logger

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(
    format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
    filename="/home/jaa/bot/ma_clipboard.log",
    level=logging.INFO)
logger=logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.info(f"enabled the logger {logger}")
```

And meanwhile in a bash shell, I tail the logfile:
`tail -f ma_clipboard.log`.

Inside the notebook, I'm working with a `python-telegram-bot`, which is handling user input from outside.

My issue is that the log-tailing doesn't update very quickly when either I purposefully log something, or even when uncaught Exceptions occur.  Sometimes I have to wait a few minutes.  This is very annoying for debugging.

I'm not sure what the source of the delay is.  The `logger` module?  The `tail` command?  Something else?    I don't think it's unique to the `python-telegram-bot` or that I'm working inside a Jupyter Notebook, as I had similar issues tail'ing a django logfile last year.

How can I reduce this latency in the logfile tailing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's PythonAnywhere dev here. <s>It takes some time for our infrastructure to write a log into the file. I'm afraid that you may not be able to do anything about that on your side.</s>

**Edit**

After closer examination, we noticed that the problem is different and it is solvable on your side. `tail -f` looks for the change of attributes of a file. Your files are accessed over [nfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System) that is caching file attributes for some time that results in delayed reaction of `tail -f`. The workaround is to `watch -n 0.1 tail [FILE]` that shows you changes to the file instantaneously. You may adjust 0.1 seconds interval to save cpu time.

Comment: Thanks for clarification.  Is there anything that can be done on the PythonAnywhere side to improve responsiveness of the logfile?

Comment: Yes, I tested this and the `watch` method consistently shows log updates faster than the original `tail -f`.  The delay in sending an update to the log and it appearing in the `watched` console is consistent (a few seconds). Previously it varied a lot, and could run many tens of seconds.

Comment: As a side-note,  `watch` seems to eat up cpu-minutes.  I left it open in a bash shell and was suprised when i hit the tarpit later.  When I looked at processes, the bash shell running watch had eaten the bulk of the minutes. (it was running nonstop for the last several days)